# Omitted second name on visa

Tags: visas, saudi-arabia

I have a Saudi Arabian e-visa, but on my passport, my first name is listed as "AA BB" (two names). However, I mistakenly omitted "BB" on the visa application, so only "AA CC" is listed as my name, where "CC" is my last name. Nonetheless, my photo, birth date, and passport number on the visa are all correct. Could this discrepancy pose a problem?

Comment: What did the visa-issuing office say when you asked?

Comment: What do you mean when I asked? It is a electronic visa.

Comment: When you contacted the KSA visa-issuing department https://ksavisa.sa/contact-us